# Docker Image Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, frontend, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I had build an React application and done docker build of that application.
I had a private docker repository and ECR repository in AWS. I want to push the image from local to there private docker repository and ECR repository.

I change the code(like api call endpoints) and again do **npm run build** and build docker image with that build. The changes is not reflected in the UI, but in the **build** **folder** the changes are reflected. I had copied that same build folder and done docker build and pushed to private repository and ECR.

Now I had pulled the same image from the ECR and run it. But the changes are not reflected in UI. I had checked the url and endpoints in network tab via inspect, In that the endpoints are not change eventhough I build so many times.

But when I change someother url and endpoints its reflecting.

What may be the issue and how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

after you make your new changes

1. build the new image with `docker build`
2. tag it with `docker tag`
3. publish it to your ECR repository.